# Laravel - Including dynamic subview file name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, laravel-blade

I am developing an e-commerce website and I would like to include a subview in my product page. The subviews are all named similar to the product name and all are located in my partials/specs folder and I want to include the subview based on the product name.

`@include('partials.specs.{{ $product->name }}')`

I tried the above code but I get the below error:

`View [partials.specs.<?php echo e($product->name); ?>] not found.`

Any advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
@include('partials.specs.' . $product->name)
```

so you just concatenate string as you do in PHP. Assuming name of product is test, it will then include view `partials.specs.test`